# Adding KML Layer to Map with Points

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I currently have a Fusion Table Map that is synced to a Google Form through a script.  It is for locations only in Oklahoma, so I am interested in adding a layer that will show the border of the state.

I made a KML Fusion Table with this information : https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col2+from+1UUVOpuu7ymfkmuzyV9dO8PXwT2QoMFuRTCy8scvn&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=34.766328945783435&lng=-97.20538659179692&t=1&z=7&l=col2&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=KML

And I would like to add it to my map here:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col3%3E%3E0+from+1EPhndJHBm0ghi06Xq9d8P62hUwCisAcQxYxgH5ax&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=36.393799473451324&lng=-94.17718371249998&t=1&z=6&l=col3%3E%3E0&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=ONE_COL_LAT_LNG

I did some research and found the example of Chicago's map from google, and tried to adapt it to my current map

```
   kmllayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query:{
      select: "geometry",
          from: "1UUVOpuu7ymfkmuzyV9dO8PXwT2QoMFuRTCy8scvn",
      });
```

So I added that to the HTML from my Fusion Table map and then tried to add the code to my website.  When I do this, I only get a blank screen.  Also, I tried to add the code to my site without the KML code above, and it still only comes up blank.  Am I missing a step?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax-error in your code, it has to be

```
   kmllayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query:{
      select: "geometry",
          from: "1UUVOpuu7ymfkmuzyV9dO8PXwT2QoMFuRTCy8scvn",
      }});
```

Working example with both layers:

```js
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35, -97),
          zoom: 6
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
          mapOptions);
        new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: "geometry",
            from: "1UUVOpuu7ymfkmuzyV9dO8PXwT2QoMFuRTCy8scvn",
          },
          map: map,
          options: {
            styleId: 2
          }
        });
        new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: "geometry",
            from: "1EPhndJHBm0ghi06Xq9d8P62hUwCisAcQxYxgH5ax",
          },
          map: map,
          options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
          }
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,
      body,
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: When I run the code here, it works and does what I want, but when I try to add it to my script, it says "#map-canvas" is not correct, when I remove the #, it wants a semicolon, and I am unable to get the script to run. Should I be trying to add this layer elsewhere? (This is my first map project, so I'm learning as I go!)